If I die, I'll have died trying
Dialog #1:
A: "Are you sure you want to climb that mountain? It looks really dangerous."
B: "Yeah, I'm determined to reach the summit. If I die, I'll have died trying."
Dialog #2:
A: "Do you really think you should confront your boss about that issue? It could jeopardize your position at the company."
B: "I understand the risks, but I can't let this opportunity pass. If I get fired, I'll have gotten fired trying to make a positive change."
Question:
Do the bolded sentences sound correct to you in the two dialogs I made up? Did I use the future perfect tense correctly? Thank you.

The two contexts aren't exactly the same. Personally, I'd replace I'll have gotten fired trying... by I'll be fired for trying... in #2, but If I die, I'll have died for trying wouldn't make sense in #1. To my ear, #1 is "short and sweet", but #2 sounds a bit verbose. I'd rather rephrase to something more like If I get fired, at least I tried [to make a positive change]. Native speakers often end an unsuccessful endeavour witrh ...at least I tried, and you probably don't need to explicitly state what you were trying to do, because it's contextually obvious.

(Syntactically, both your phrasings sound fine to me. But I'm British, and gotten is primarily American, so they may say different.)

They are fine. In the UK, they use got instead of gotten. In the US, they use gotten. However, use whatever English floats your boat.

Just for the hell of it, I searched Google Books for both "If I die, I'll have died trying" and "If I die, I'll die trying". No exact matches for either, but "If I die, at least I tried" gets a couple of hits. Anyway, the point is we can be very flexible about the verb form following at least that particular if... condition!

How about "If I die, at least I won't have to worry about the correct grammatical construction any more."?

If I should die, think only this of me:
That there's some corner of a foreign field
That is for ever England.  There shall be
In that rich earth a richer dust concealed....
